# Send data from browser to C#/Java via socket

Tags: c#, javascript

How can I send packets of data from HTML and javascript running locally to a C# application running locally?

I can't get a HTML page to handshake with a C# implementation of websockets because the handshakes in `node` are version specific - I don't know enough about how to examine the network traffic to tweak any of the C# server examples I've found. It keeps failing on the initial handshake. When I try to send data straight from a browser to a javascript implementation of websockets it works straight away, but that's not what I need. The version of `node` I'm running in javascript to try this is v0.10.29.

Is there any other way to do this without websockets? Could I send UDP packets from a webpage running locally (in the  `null` origin) to a C# app if I disable some security features of Opera or Chrome?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, you cannot send bare TCP/IP or UDP data from JavaScript in a webpage (there are various proposals to change this, but they'll all require various handshake methods for security).

If you explain more about what problems you've had using WebSockets, I may be able to help; you can use Fiddler 4.5 to view WebSocket traffic, including the original handshake as well as the WebSocket messages.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) in this case? And another option is using [Socket IO](http://socket.io/). I see some of example that used Socket IO to communicate with Windows App [here](http://isolasoftware.it/2012/05/04/how-to-send-live-data-from-a-c-desktop-application-to-web-using-websockets/). Hope this help.